# Why is my proxy armature not highlighting when selected?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a simple character rigged with Rigify and in the file itself the controllers highlight when selected.

[image]

But if I link the geo and rig collections into a new file and create a rig proxy I can still select controllers but they no longer highlight.

[image]

This is how the outliner looks in the original file...

[image]

And how it's setup in a new file with proxy

[image]

What might I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to tick "In Front" in the armature panel "Viewport Display" and now I can select the armature with highlighting.